# Use shared_ptr among member functions as private variable C++

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I would like to reuse the `shared_ptr` among a few member functions in a class.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class TestClass
{
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<int> int_shared_ptr;

    public:
        TestClass()
        {
            std::cout << "I will create a shared ptr object here.";
            std::shared_ptr<int> int_ptr (new int(10));
            std::shared_ptr<int> int_shared_ptr(int_ptr);
            std::cout << "The created shared ptr has value of " << *int_shared_ptr << "\n";

        }

        void check_if_shared()
        {
            std::cout << "The created shared ptr has value of " <<  int_shared_ptr << "\n";
        }

};


int main(){

    auto tc = TestClass();
    tc.check_if_shared();


}
```

Output

```
I will create a shared ptr object here.The created shared ptr has value of 10
The created shared ptr has value of 0
```

The `int_shared_ptr` seems destroyed once it leaves the constructor. Can anyone suggest a way to keep the shared pointer after leaving the constructor?

Comment: You have two variables with the same name.  One is a member variable, the other is local to the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
std::shared_ptr<int> int_shared_ptr(int_ptr);
```

creates a function local variable of the same name as the member variable. The member variable is left default-initialized. Use:

```
TestClass() : int_shared_ptr(new int(10))
{
    std::cout << "The created shared ptr has value of " << *int_shared_ptr << "\n";
}
```

It is more idiomatic to use [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared):

```
TestClass() : int_shared_ptr(std::make_shared<int>(10))
{
    std::cout << "The created shared ptr has value of " << *int_shared_ptr << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Indeed, the `int_shared_ptr` was a local variable. Your suggestion works well in this case. A further question is what if the private variable initialisation is more complex. Does it possible to initialise `int_shared_ptr` inside the constructor? Thanks!

Comment: @CaoYu Write a function that does the complex thing and returns a shared pointer, and initialise the member by calling the function.

Comment: @CaoYu, you would use a function to encapsulate the complex logic and use its return value to initialize the member variable. `TestClass(arguments): my_variable(TestClass::complexFunction(arguments)) {}`

Answer (score 1):

So I think you are trying to save reference to the same `int` with multiple shared pointers - instance members. What about this simple solution:

```
#include <memory>

class TestClass
{
    private:
        // you can have any number of shared pointers here

        std::shared_ptr<int> shared_0;
        std::shared_ptr<int> shared_1;
        std::shared_ptr<int> shared_2;

    public:
        TestClass()
        {
            // create new int once
            shared_0 = std::make_shared<int>(10);

            // copy references only
            shared_1 = shared_0;
            shared_2 = shared_0;

            std::cout << "shared_0: " << *shared_0 
                << "\nshared_1: " << *shared_1 
                << "\nshared_2: " << *shared_2 << "\n";
        }

        void check_if_shared()
        {
            std::cout << "shared_0: " << *shared_0 
                << "\nshared_1: " << *shared_1 
                << "\nshared_2: " << *shared_2 << "\n";
        }
};

int main()
{
    auto tc = TestClass();
    tc.check_if_shared();

    // now all shared pointers point to the same int
}
```

Output:

```
shared_0: 10
shared_1: 10
shared_2: 10
shared_0: 10
shared_1: 10
shared_2: 10
```

Comment: @CaoYu As a you are new user I would like to remind you that you can accept one of the answers.

Comment: Sure, I have upvoted your answer as well. (May not shown publicly because my reputation is not yet > 15)